# Loading property file from filesystem using util:properties?

Tags: spring, configuration, properties

When i try to load a property file from the filesystem using util:properties, the property file is not found. I placed it on my root drive and all kinds of places but i seem not to be able to load a property file from the filesystem using util:properties.

Is it possible to do this?

```
<util:properties id="configProperties" location="file:///d:/config.properties"/>
```

Loading it from the classpath works ok.. but i want to configure the application so a system admin can change the properties.

```
<util:properties id="configProperties" location="classpath:/config.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this in a Linux project and it works fine:

```
<util:properties id="jdbcConfiguration" location="file:///home/reporting/jdbc.properties"/>
```

so the problem is probably with the way you specify the path. Try it this way:

```
<util:properties id="configProperties" location="file:d:/config.properties"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i was sure i tried this yesterday late in the evening.. But i made a mistake :) I had the util:properties in 2 different spring xml files, both pointing to a wrong location.. I cleaned it up, implemented your suggestion and it works perfect!